# Oracle procedure using NUMTODSINTERVAL

Tags: oracle, intervals, procedure

Is it possible to use NUMTODSINTERVAL inside a procedure. If so, why doesn't this code work?

Sorry for the jibberish but stackoverflow was complaining I had to add more text

Xxxxxxxxxxx
Yyyyyyyyggggggg
Xxxxxxxxx

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CREATE_XXX
 (
  i_schedule_id IN PLS_INTEGER,
i_base_date IN DATE,
  i_offset IN PLS_INTEGER DEFAULT 0, 
i_incr IN PLS_INTEGER DEFAULT 10,
  i_duration         IN PLS_INTEGER DEFAULT 5
  )
 AS 
 l_schedule_id PLS_INTEGER;
l_base_date DATE;
I_offset  PLS_INTEGER;

 BEGIN 

    SELECT i_schedule_id              
INTO  l_schedule_id FROM DUAL; 

     SELECT          i_base_date 
INTO  l_base_date  FROM DUAL; 

 l_offset :=
NUMTODSINTERVAL(i_offset, 'SECOND') 


END;
/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Why doesn't this code work" isn't particularly helpful without some description of what isn't working.  In this case, I'll assume that we're just talking about the syntax errors in your code.

If we run your code as posted, we'll get the compilation error

> Errors: PROCEDURE CREATE_XXX Line/Col: 26/1 PLS-00103: Encountered the
> symbol "END" when expecting one of the following:
>
> . ( * % & = - + ; < / > at in is mod remainder not rem    <an
> exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like like2    like4
> likec between || multiset member submultiset The symbol ";" was
> substituted for "END" to continue.

That's because line 26, the `numtodsinterval` call is missing the semicolon at the end

```
 l_offset :=
NUMTODSINTERVAL(i_offset, 'SECOND') ;
```

That would leave us with the compilation error

> Errors: PROCEDURE CREATE_XXX Line/Col: 0/0 PL/SQL: Compilation unit
> analysis terminated Line/Col: 1/1 PLS-00410: duplicate fields in
> RECORD,TABLE or argument list are not permitted

That's because `i_offset` is declared both as a parameter to the procedure and a local variable.  I assume your intention was to use the `l_` prefix for local variables.

```
 AS 
   l_schedule_id PLS_INTEGER;
   l_base_date DATE;
   l_offset  PLS_INTEGER;
```

Fixing that, now the syntax error is

> Errors: PROCEDURE CREATE_XXX Line/Col: 21/2 PL/SQL: Statement ignored
> Line/Col: 22/1 PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type

Line 22 is the `numtodsinterval` call.  And this error is because `numtodsinterval` returns an `interval day to second` but you're trying to assign it to a local variable of type `pls_integer`.  We need to change the data type

```
 AS 
   l_schedule_id PLS_INTEGER;
   l_base_date DATE;
   l_offset  interval day to second;
 BEGIN
```

That causes the code to compile successfully.  The code still has problems at this point, but it compiles.

- There doesn't appear to be any reason to declare `l_schedule_id` or `l_base_date` as local variables.  You can just use the parameters that are passed in.
- If you are going to declare those variables, just use the assignment operator `:=` to assign the local variable the value from the input parameter rather than doing a `select ... from dual`.